# How to debug long-running mapreduce jobs with millions of writes?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am using the simple `control.start_map()` function of the [appengine-mapreduce](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) library to start a mapreduce job.  This job successfully completes and shows ~43M mapper-calls on the resulting `/mapreduce/detail?mapreduce_id=<my_id>` page.  However, this page makes no mention of the reduce step or any of the underlying appengine-pipeline processes that I believe are still running.  Is there some way to return the pipeline ID that this calls makes so I can look at the underlying pipelines to help debug this long-running job?  I would like to retrieve enough information to pull up this page:  `/mapreduce/pipeline/status?root=<guid>`

Here is an example of the code I am using to start up my mapreduce job originally:

```
from third_party.mapreduce import control
mapreduce_id = control.start_map(
    name="Backfill",
    handler_spec="mark_tos_accepted",
    reader_spec=(
        "third_party.mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreInputReader"),
    mapper_parameters={
        "input_reader": {
            "entity_kind": "ModelX"
        },
    },
    shard_count=64,
    queue_name="backfill-mapreduce-queue",
 )
```

Here is the mapping function:

```
# This is where we keep our copy of appengine-mapreduce
from third_party.mapreduce import operation as op

def mark_tos_accepted(modelx):
    # Skip users who have already been marked
    if (not modelx
        or modelx.tos_accepted == myglobals.LAST_MATERIAL_CHANGE_TO_TOS):
    return

    modelx.tos_accepted = user_models.LAST_MATERIAL_CHANGE_TO_TOS
    yield op.db.Put(modelx)
```

Here are the relevant portions of the ModelX:

```
class BackupModel(db.Model):
    backup_timestamp = db.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True, auto_now=True)

class ModelX(BackupModel):
    tos_accepted = db.IntegerProperty(indexed=False, default=0)
```

For more context, I am trying to debug a problem I am seeing with writes showing up in our data warehouse.

On 3/23/2013, we launched a MapReduce job (let's call it `A`) over a db.Model (let's call it `ModelX`) with ~43M entities.  7 hours later, the job "finished" and the `/mapreduce/detail` page showed that we had successfully mapped over all of the entities, as shown below.

```
mapper-calls: 43613334 (1747.47/sec avg.)
```

On 3/31/2013, we launched another MapReduce job (let's call it B) over `ModelX`. 12 hours later, the job finished with status Success and the  `/mapreduce/detail` page showed that we had successfully mapped over all of the entities, as shown below.

```
mapper-calls: 43803632 (964.24/sec avg.)
```

I know that MR job A wrote to all `ModelX` entities, since we introduced a new property that none of the entities contained before.  The `ModelX` contains an auto_add property like so.

```
backup_timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True, auto_now=True)
```

Our data warehousing process runs a query over `ModelX` to find those entities that changed on a certain day and then downloads those entities and stores them in a separate (AWS) database so that we can run analysis over them.  An example of this query is:

```
db.GqlQuery('select * from ModelX where backup_timestamp >= DATETIME(2013, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0) and backup_timestamp < DATETIME(2013, 4, 11, 0, 0, 0) order by backup_timestamp')
```

I would expect that our data warehouse would have ~43M entities on each of the days that the MR jobs completed, but it is actually more like ~3M, with each subsequent day showing an increase, as shown in this progression:

```
3/16/13 230751
3/17/13 193316
3/18/13 344114
3/19/13 437790
3/20/13 443850
3/21/13 640560
3/22/13 612143
3/23/13 547817
3/24/13 2317784  // Why isn't this ~43M ?
3/25/13 3701792  // Why didn't this go down to ~500K again?
3/26/13 4166678
3/27/13 3513732
3/28/13 3652571
```

This makes me think that although the op.db.Put() calls issued by the mapreduce job are still running in some pipeline or queue and causing this trickle effect.

Furthermore, if I query for entities with an old `backup_timestamp`, I can go back pretty far and still get plenty of entities, but I would expect all of these queries to return 0:

```
In [4]: ModelX.all().filter('backup_timestamp <', 'DATETIME(2013,2,23,1,1,1)').count()
Out[4]: 1000L

In [5]: ModelX.all().filter('backup_timestamp <', 'DATETIME(2013,1,23,1,1,1)').count()
Out[5]: 1000L

In [6]: ModelX.all().filter('backup_timestamp <', 'DATETIME(2012,1,23,1,1,1)').count()
Out[6]: 1000L
```

However, there is this strange behavior where the query returns entities that it should not:

```
In [8]: old = ModelX.all().filter('backup_timestamp <', 'DATETIME(2012,1,1,1,1,1)')

In [9]: paste
for o in old[1:100]:
  print o.backup_timestamp
## -- End pasted text --
2013-03-22 22:56:03.877840
2013-03-22 22:56:18.149020
2013-03-22 22:56:19.288400
2013-03-22 22:56:31.412290
2013-03-22 22:58:37.710790
2013-03-22 22:59:14.144200
2013-03-22 22:59:41.396550
2013-03-22 22:59:46.482890
2013-03-22 22:59:46.703210
2013-03-22 22:59:57.525220
2013-03-22 23:00:03.864200
2013-03-22 23:00:18.040840
2013-03-22 23:00:39.636020
```

Which makes me think that the index is just taking a long time to be updated.

I have also graphed the number of entities that our data warehousing downloads and am noticing some cliff-like drops that makes me think that there is some behind-the-scenes throttling going on somewhere that I cannot see with any of the diagnostic tools exposed on the appengine dashboard.  For example, this graph shows a fairly large spike on 3/23, when we started the mapreduce job, but then a dramatic fall shortly thereafter.

This graph shows the count of entities returned by the `BackupTimestamp` `GqlQuery` for each 10-minute interval for each day.  Note that the purple line shows a huge spike as the MapReduce job spins up, and then a dramatic fall ~1hr later as the throttling kicks in.  This graph also shows that there seems to be some time-based throttling going on.

[image: Datastore reads per 10-min increment, per day]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll have any reducer functions there, because all you've done is start a mapper. To do a complete mapreduce, you have to explicitly instantiate a [`MapReducePipeline`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/mapreducepipelineclass) and call `start` on it. As a bonus, that answers your question, as it returns the pipeline ID which you can then use in the status URL.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'd rather not start another 43M-write pipeline to debug this.  I have added some additional context to the question if that help.  I have also engaged GAE enterprise support in hopes of getting a deeper understanding of what's going on, so we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to understand the specific problem. Is it that you are expecting a bigger number of entities in your AWS database? I would suspect that the problem lies with the process that downloads your old ModelX entities into an AWS database, that it's somehow not catching all the updated entities.

Is the AWS-downloading process modifying ModelX in any way? If not, then why would you be surprised at finding entities with an old `modified` time stamp? `modified` would only be updated on writes, not on read operations.

Kind of unrelated - with respect to throttling I've usually found a throttled task queue to be the problem, so maybe check how old your tasks in there are or if your app is being throttled due to a large amount of errors incurred somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I expect the mapreduce to report write-success at the same rate my download script detects them.  Instead, the mapreduce reports 43M writes have completed, but my download script only detects 3M.  I am surprised that there are old modified timestamps because the mapreduce told me it had already finished writing every single `ModelX` entity.  The AWS-downloader is read-only.  The `backfill-mapreduce-queue` does not show abnormally queued tasks.  Nothing in the GAE dashboards show that my mapreduce is still running, hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

control.start_map doesn't use pipeline and has no shuffle/reduce step. When the mapreduce status page shows its finished, all mapreduce related taskqueue tasks should have finished. You can examine your queue or even pause it.

I suspect there are problems related to old indexes for the old Model or to eventual consistency. To debug MR, it is useful to filter your warnings/errors log and search by the mr id. To help with your particular case, it might be useful to see your Map handler.